# How to find number of convex deficiency region in image with the help of opencv

Tags: c++

I am working on project. I need to find number of convex deficiency region in image.Is there any function in opencv which can find number of convex deficiency region in image.

Comment: Check "convexityDefects" on opencv documentation

Comment: Is this code right for calculating convex deficient region? findContours( rois[wp], contourss, hierarchyy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );vector<vector<int> > hullsI(contourss.size()); 
        vector<vector<Vec4i> > defects(contourss.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < contourss.size(); i++)
        {
        convexHull(contourss[i], hullsI[i], false); 
        if(hullsI[i].size() > 3 )            
        {
        convexityDefects(contourss[i], hullsI[i], defects[i]);
        }
 f24=f24+defects[i].size();}
 cout<<f24<<"\n";

Answer (score 0):

Can this be any helpful to you :

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/hull/hull.html

[image: Convex Hull results]

[image: Convex Deficiency]

Comment: I want to find number of convex deficient region,not convex hull

Comment: I am new in Opencv

Comment: Does the line around hand match the shaded area of the convex hull in the image below? what do you want to get from it, area or what ?

Comment: I want to find "number" of convex deficient region in image of a table in document image.

Comment: for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
{  vector<int> hullIndices; 
 vector<Vec4i> convexityDefects;


convexHull(contours[i], hullIndices, true,false);
convexityDefects(contours[i], hullIndices, convexityDefects);
}
int depth;
for (int j = 0; j < convexityDefects.size(); j++)
{
 int startIdx = convexityDefects[j].val[0];
 int endIdx = convexityDefects[j].val[1];
 int defectPtIdx = convexityDefects[j].val[2];
 depth = (double)convexityDefects[j].val[3]/256.0f; 
}
 cout<<"depth = "<<depth;

Comment: My code after finding number of contours in an image

Comment: error: no match for call to ‘(std::vector<std::vector<cv::Vec<int, 4> > >) (std::vector<cv::Point_<int> >&, std::vector<int>&, std::vector<std::vector<cv::Vec<int, 4> > >&)’
 convexityDefects(contours[i], hullIndices, convexityDefects);